# Why does `find` sometimes find my file, sometimes not

Tags: find, wildcards

Here is my directory tree (not showing all dirs, files, just the essential):

```
a_root_dir/ (directory)
a_root_dir/dynamo/local/run.sh
a_root_dir/dynamo/local/run_local.sh
```

Now when I do

```
> cd a_root_dir
> find . -name *.sh
./dynamo/local/run.sh
########### IT DOESN'T SHOW run_local.sh !!!!
> cd dynamo
> pwd
...../a_root_dir/dynamo
> find . -name *.sh
./local/run.sh
./local/run_local.sh
######## NOW IT FOUND IT
```

How come this happens?

Files and directories and scripts are "usual", **there is no symlink**.
Many thanks

Comment: Can you paste output of `tree a_root_dir`?

Comment: Also see here:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123440/why-is-my-find-not-recursive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your asterisk is interpreted by the shell BEFORE it is passed to `find` as an argument.

I.e. if you have a file like `script.sh` in the current working directory from where you execute find, your command will look `like` this:

```
#command you type:
find . -name *.sh
#command the shell creates:
find . -name script.sh
```

So in your case it is the first match for `*.sh` in `a_root_dir` as interpreted by the shell, and your command literally is this:

```
find . -name run.sh
```

What you need to do is using hard quotes to suppress the shell expanding the asterisk before `find` is executed:

```
find . -name '*.sh'
```